# Connecting to a VPN client that does not use the VPN gateway

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn, dd-wrt

### I am trying to "merge" 2 networks, so we get access to each other's files.

The setup consists of my computer, my dd-wrt R7000 router, the remote router (a shitty tp-link) and the remote computer. Both computers are running Windows 10 v2004 or later.

To do that I chose the most obvious option I had - I enabled the PPTP VPN Server on my router.

Both networks are on a different subnet. My side (host network) is on 192.168.0.xxx, the guest side is on 192.168.1.xxx, to avoid IP conflicts.

The VPN clients have no trouble accessing my computer on the host network.

However there is a network setting on the clients that seems to lead to a functional conflict.

In the VPN connection properties -> Networking -> IPv4 properties -> Advanced there is a setting called **Use default gateway on remote network**.

**OFF** = Prevents guest internet traffic from tunneling through the VPN (VPN performance is fairly low). Prevents host network from accessing guest machine over the network (cannot map drives).
**ON** = Tunnels guest internet traffic through VPN. Allows host network to access guest machine.

**The goal is for guest internet traffic to not tunnel through the VPN (due to the low performance) and for the host network to be able to access the guest machine (the reason for doing this in the first place).**

Is this possible? How?
(Some theory as to what's going on, so I learn some networking magic also appreciated.)

A different approach that accomplishes the goal of mutual network shares over the internet under the stated hardware constraints is also a valid answer to this question.

Comment: Security is not a consideration, just wanna share photos, videos and memes. If you read the post you'd see your next statement is false. And finally hardware VPN boxes goes outside of the constraints I already specified in the question.

Comment: when you try to map network drives, are you using hostnames or IPs or FQDNs? so my first guess is that when the feature in question is off, that your systems are having trouble with resolving remote hostnames to IPs. Naming systems are commonly a problem when working with VPNs.

Comment: IPs. Maybe I can do something with manually setting gateways or routes in cmd, but I'm learning this as I go - I'm not a network engineer. This problem will probably be educational to decipher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After staring at the routing tables for a long time (I'm not a network engineer), and a lot of experiments, I figured out the solution.

1. Disable **Use default gateway on remote network** in *VPN connection properties -> Networking -> IPv4 properties -> Advanced*
2. Run the following in an elevated terminal:

```
route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 if xx
```

Where `xx` is the number(not address) of your VPN network interface (*if* stands for interface, not a conditional). You can discover that number via `route print`.

What this does:

1. Prevents all traffic from being routed through the VPN. Windows automatically adds a route for those destinations which are only reachable through the remote gateway (that being the remote network).
2. Adds a route capable of routing ALL traffic through the VPN. However (at least in my instance) that route is automatically assigned a higher metric(aka distance), making it less preferred(more "costly") than the non-VPN route. Meaning anything that CAN go through the non-VPN route WILL go through it.

I don't rightly know WHY this fixes my problem, because I still don't know what exactly the problem is, maybe the new route catches some ACK or something that arrives from the host-network PC that otherwise gets dropped.